# Bind input model to every object in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I have a simple `input` like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" />
```

and an array in my controller like this:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.arr = [
        {str: ''},
        {str: ''}
    ];
});
```

How to bind my `input`s model to the `str` attribute of every single object in my `arr`?

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/xvpnyx63/)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `ng-controller` > ... > `ng-repeat`

Comment: @Tushar I want just one `input` which controls content of any object in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `ng-change` directive and update the `scope` using `angular.forEach`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr = [{
    str: ''
  }, {
    str: ''
  }];
  $scope.updateIt = function(myModel) {
    angular.forEach($scope.arr, function(value, key) {
      value.str = myModel;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <code>{{arr}}</code>
  <br />
  <br />
  <!-- bind input model to every object 'str' -->
  <input type="text" ng-model="myModel" ng-change='updateIt(myModel)' />
</div>
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/xvpnyx63/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Rayon I was also thinking of this and was just wondering if there is a template-only solution for this kind of binding.

Comment: Without trying to dive specifically into *Angular* here, this might be a good application for HTML/JavaScript's existing mechanism of "event bubbling."  Instead of trying to bind to every `<input>` tag, bind just once to their *container.*  The code for the container will then have to determine which one of the child tags triggered the event.  But this will work no matter how many child tags there are.